# waiting for sqlcmd job to finsih before next batch step

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I currently have this in a cmd file....

```
sqlcmd -s myserver -u user -p pass -i step1.sql -o step1output.txt
timeout 5
sqlcmd -s myserver -u user -p pass -i step2.sql -o step2output.txt
timeout 5
sqlcmd -s myserver -u user -p pass -Q "USE MSDB EXEC sp_start_job @job_name = 'MyJob'"

sqlcmd -s myserver -u user -p pass -i step3.sql -o step3output.txt
```

in between the sqljob running and step3, how do I "wait" for the job to complete before going to step3?

Answer (score 0):

Jobs are run asynchronously by design.

However, you could include a waitfor loop in the step3.sql and check `dbo.sysjobs` joined to `dbo.sysjobactivity` for current status of the job.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190484.aspx